# Concatenate list after button JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, concatenation

I have to make a web page that when I click a button, it adds the number of times clicked each time to a list:

- You have clicked 1 times
- You have clicked 2 times
- You have clicked 3 times

I have the button, and I can have it display the number of times, but I need it to list it out.

How do I create a growing list on my page?

Comment: Huh, list it out how exactly, how are we supposed to know what that even means ?

Comment: Post your Html or whatever script you have tried. No one will code from scratch.

Comment: I assume right now you're storing a variable that just holds the number, and you update it.  Perhaps what you want is to store an array and push a new value onto it?  It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: its supposed to look like a list, with each line going under neath it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
var i = 0;
function pew(){
    i++;
$('div').append('<li>'+ i +'</li>'); 
}
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU! THANKS. I know javascript, but the JQuery is new to me.